# MongoDB Transactions: WriteConflict Error

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, transactions

**Environment**:

- MongoDB:  (Atlas 4+)
- Driver: 4.2.3
- We are using Spring Boot Data MongoDB (2.5.4)

We are using MongoDB Transactions using the callback API. Same happens with Core API as well.

**Sample**:

```
    private ThreadLocal<MongoOperations> sessionMongoTemplate;

    try (final ClientSession session = getClientSession()) {
       this.sessionMongoTemplate = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> getMongoOperations().withSession(session));

       session.withTransaction(() -> {
           // do some work
           // call a method which does (sessionMongoTemplate.get().insert(entity);) 
           // (this throws WriteConflict Error)
       });
   }
```

**Error**:

*com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 112 (WriteConflict): 'WriteConflict error: this operation conflicted with another operation. Please retry your operation or multi-document transaction.' on server abc.mongodb.net:1234. The full response is
{
"errorLabels": [
"TransientTransactionError"
],
"ok": 0,
"errmsg": "WriteConflict error: this operation conflicted with another operation. Please retry your operation or multi-document transaction.",
"code": 112,
"codeName": "WriteConflict"*

**Query:**
We associated MongoOperations/Template with ClientSession already.
That session opened a transaction.
However, when code uses the SessionScoped MongoOperations, it fails as if it has no knowledge of opened transaction.

Can we not use this approach?

> As per the example in :
> https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/core/transactions-in-applications/
> within transaction body, we used MongoClient and it works fine. Can we
> not use SessionScoped MongoTemplate?

Comment: It would be helpful if you include error details.  A writeConflict could be a duplicate key exception, which can occur within a single transaction with no other activity on the system.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have added the Error. The label in error is TransientTransactionError - which should be retried by session for Callback API documentation. That's where the confusion is.

Answer (score 5):

So, after some digging, this is what I think is happening...

With a database operation (command, such as insert or update), if not in an ACID transaction, conflicting operations (the second session in your example) will block behind the current operation's commit with a retry.  Keep in mind, outside of ACID transactions MongoDB has document level atomicity.

But, with multi-document transactions, the behavior is different.  If a writeConflict is encountered it fails immediately.  The strategy is designed this way to allow your application to detect this condition, then wait X milliseconds and retry N times, where X and N are your comfort levels.

The parameter you are setting has nothing to do with how long a second session will block and wait, but has to do with how long the system is allowed to wait before a lock can be established.  The default is 5ms.
Your example shows 3 seconds (3000ms).  Presumably you were referring to the lock on session number 2 - how long you allow it to take to acquire a lock.  The problem is that the writeConflict was detected before any attempt to acquire a lock, because in ACID transactions the application is expected to perform the wait, not the driver.

Comment: Thanks again @barrypicker.

Are you considering the call to sessionMongoTemplate as 'second' transaction. I had already bound the session to MongoTemplate using withSession(). Now within the session,.withTransaction() body, same transaction is used. (As one transaction is bound to only one session). 

Where do you see the second session/transaction?

Comment: @amit.shipra - Sessions were introduced into MongoDB at version 3.6.  Transactions were later added in version 4.0.  Transactions use sessions.  You can issue a command with no reference to a session or transaction.  These will use the implicit session, but with no transaction support (i.e. no *multi-document* transaction guarantees where the atomicity is at the document level only).  If you use the driver this way (i.e., no transactions) your second (would-be conflicting writes) operations will retry automatically.